# Sklearn - Diferença entre preprocessing.scale() e preprocessing.StandardScaler()

Tags: machine-learning, sklearn, ciência-de-dados

Olá!

Sou iniciante em Data Science e Machine Learning, desculpem se a dúvida é meio "besta".

Entendo a importância da padronização/normalizacão das features e em meus estudos, sempre me deparo com o uso do StandardScaler(). Estudando através da documentação do Sklearn, vi que também existe o preprocessing.scale() e na prática, tanto o StandardScaler() como somente Scaler()em meu teste resultou na mesma coisa.

A documentação diz que o StandardScaler() aplica "transformer API". O que seria isso?
Qual a diferença ao utilizar o preprocessing.scale() x preprocessing.StandardScaler() ?

Meus testes:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                    [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1., -1.]])

X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
X_scaled ## Features padronizadas
```

out[ ]:

```
array([[ 0.        , -1.22474487,  1.33630621],
       [ 1.22474487,  0.        , -0.26726124],
       [-1.22474487,  1.22474487, -1.06904497]])
```

Utilizando o StandardScaler():

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
StandardScaler()

scaler.mean_

scaler.scale_

scaler.transform(X_train)
```

out [ ]

```
array([[ 0.        , -1.22474487,  1.33630621],
       [ 1.22474487,  0.        , -0.26726124],
       [-1.22474487,  1.22474487, -1.06904497]])
```

Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Qual a diferença ao utilizar o `preprocessing.scale()` Vs `preprocessing.StandardScaler()`?**

Ambos o `StandardScaler().fit(X_train)` e o `scale(X_train)` realizam a mesma operação, mas o primeiro gera uma classe, enquanto o segundo apenas escalona os dados.

Caso tenha um `X_train` e um `X_test`, o correto é escalonar ambos os conjuntos de dados pela média e desvio padrão apenas do `X_train`. É neste cenário que o `StandardScaler()` entra:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Caso tenha apenas um único conjunto de dados e esse escalonamento só será realizado uma única vez, o `preprocessing.scale()` é suficiente.

**2) A documentação diz que o StandardScaler() aplica "transformer API". O que seria isso?**

A [documentação](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling) diz:

> The `preprocessing` module further provides a utility class StandardScaler that implements the `Transformer` API to compute the mean and standard deviation on a training set so as to be able to later reapply the same transformation on the testing set.

> O módulo `preprocessing` ainda fornece uma classe utilitária StandardScaler que implementa a API `Transformer` para calcular a média e o desvio padrão em um conjunto de treino para que seja possível reutilizar a mesma transformação no conjunto de teste.

Essa API `Transformer` é uma referência ao modulo `Transformer` do sklearn, utilizado para transformar os dados. Esse módulo é aplamente usado pelo próprio sklearn em seus [prórpio métodos](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html), mas podemos fazer [um personalizado](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers).